# Can different world states issue passports with the same "number"?

Tags: passports

Typically, passport numbers are not just running indices of the passports issued, but have certain rules regarding relating the numbers, use of letters, and/or suffixes and prefixes.

Is it the case, that you can determine which world state issued a passport based solely on the "number" (i.e. digit-and-letter combination referred to as the passport number)? Or can different states issue passports with the same number?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The passport number itself is not normalised, can have different lengths and structures depending both on the country and when it was issued, can use the same number for different passports issued by different countries, and usually does not include any information about the issuing country.

However, the MRZ (machine readable zone, the two lines at the bottom of the bio page) is standardised and includes both the issuer country and the passport number (and more information).

Comment: +1 Whenever a form (paper or online) has asked for my passport number it has also needed the issuing country, unless that is already determined by context.

Comment: But do different countries actually have overlapping valid passport numbers? As opposed to complete MRZs?

Comment: @einpoklum it is difficult to know (unless you find actual collisions) as the structure of those numbers is usually not published, but you most definitely can’t assume they are globally unique without the country code. Note that many passport actually have a line in the bio page that contains P, the issuing country’s 3-letter ISO code, and the passport number. That combination should be unique.

Comment: According to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/eu-passport-number there are many countries which use 8 or 9 digit numbers. This give 100 million or one billion numbers, which is most probably not enough for uniquely numbering all passports in the world.

Comment: Actually probably even less, given that in many cases one of the digits is a checksum or similar validity verification number.

Comment: @jcaron the ICAO standard calls for passport numbers to be nine digits in the MRZ, to which is added a checksum digit.  There's also a checksum for the entire MRZ. A country can of course choose to make one of the 9 digits a checksum as well, but we can be fairly certain that at least one country doesn't do that: the US doesn't use alphabetical characters in its regular passport numbers, and a pool of 100,000,000 passport numbers would not last very long.  But what is that document you link to?  It seems to have overlooked the fact that Belgians also speak French.

Comment: @phoog there are lots of different strategies for allocation of passport numbers, difficult to say which ones have checksums or not. Note that [this document](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/check-document-numbers/check-document-numbers.pdf) links to various national tools which can check passport numbers. No idea if they check a database for validity or just format/checksum. The doc linked above is the one part of the rules Microsoft used in some services to detect the presence of sensitive information (and block or warn or whatever they do). It’s not probably not perfect.

Comment: @jcaron Looking at some of the sites (like checkdoc.be) these seem to be official government sites that use a database of issued documents and makes sure that it is not expired or stolen